# How do you control size of imported SVG's in Three.js?

Tags: svg, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am importing an SVG using the `SVGLoader` and turning each path into a mesh that is then put into a group. When I do so, the group is much larger than I would like it to be. Rather than scaling, I'd like to import it at the correct size to begin with. When I change the `width` and `height` attributes on the SVG: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25">` nothing changes with respect to the size of the rendered meshes. I haven't seen anything actually describing how SVG sizes are determined by the loader. Is it a viewbox? Is there something special that has to be done?

Answer (score 0):

In your 3d world, you can only change the size of your object by `Object3D.scale.set(x, y, z)`,and the x, y, z value determine the size of your mesh in you 3d world. When you change the width and height attributes on the SVG, you can only change the resolution but not the size

Comment: Does that mean that every SVG would be imported at the same size?

Comment: yep, the width and height of svg wouldn't affect the size of `Object3D` in ht 3d world, the only way to change the size of `Object3D` is changing its property `scale`

Comment: Thanks for the info. One last question: is it possible to extract the SVG paths from its `ViewBox` once it has been loaded and rendered? On the [example for the SVG Loader](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=svg#webgl_loader_svg) if you switch to example 6, you will see it is offset. I checked the SVG file on GH and it is due to the files viewBox. In theory, could you set the VB to shrink the SVG then extract it so you don't have random empty space on the object?